# How to disable html inspector in js source in PhpStorm?

Tags: javascript, html, phpstorm, inspector

Subj.

I need to disable HTML inspector in JS strings.
Look a screenshot

[image: screenshot]

ALT+Enter does not have "Un-inject language" option.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you cannot un-inject any language from JavaScript string: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-1475